# Collections.nCopies() vs. For-loop Initialization

Tags: java, performance, collections

I recently found out that you can initialize Lists in Java by calling the `Collections.nCopies()`method rather than using a for-loop. But that got me wondering, is there a performance advantage/disadvantage in using this method over a for-loop or is it just a simpler way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried to test this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the collection returned by `nCopies` is immutable, the entries in this collection need not be "materialized". In other words, all that is needed is a space for a single object of type `T`; everything else is an implementation of the collection interface that pretends to have a collection of `N` objects, but in reality has only one object that it returns `N` times.

This may prove to give you a lot of improvement in space when the collection you are creating is large: in fact, the larger the collection, the bigger is your savings compared to a real collection that you initialize with a `for` loop.

Comment: +1 - For completeness, it is worth noting that the `nCopies` method in Java 6 and Java 7 *does* behave this way (I checked the code), and that there is no reason to expect that to change for future versions.

Comment: Because it returns an immutable collection, does that affect the add() method for an ArrayList?

Comment: @OmarAbdeldayem yes, you'll get a `RuntimeException` surely a `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: @OmarAbdeldayem That's the thing, it returns an implementation of `List<T>` that is not an `ArrayList`. It's an internal class of `Collections` called `CopiesList` ([demo](http://ideone.com/RlB9cE)). The `CopiesList` does not let you `add`, `remove`, or `put` any object into it - you get an exception instead.

Comment: Also, because there is only a single object of type `T`, does changing that object at one index affect the entire collection? **EDIT:  Just tried it out and it does.** Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Immutability is not an issue when you are using nCopies() as the argument to a List constructor: the constructor creates a copy, which is not immutable.