# Java8 stream: Iterate over nested list

Tags: java, list, java-8, nested, java-stream

Trying to get my head round the Java 8 streams syntax with a simple example. Had a look at the other similar questions on this topic, but could not find any solutions that would match my example and would work for me.

I have a class as follow

```
import java.util.List;

public class Car {
    private String model;
    private String make;
    private String carName;
    private List<Specification> specification;


    public Car(String model, String make, String carName, List<Specification> specification) {
        this.model = model;
        this.make = make;
        this.carName = carName;
        this.specification = specification;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }

    public List<Specification> getSpecification() {
        return specification;
    }
}


public class Specification {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Specification(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And I have the main method

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RegisterCar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<String> carNames = new ArrayList<>();
        carNames.add("Audi");
        carNames.add("BMW");
        carNames.add("Toyota");
       
        List<String> colour = new ArrayList<>();
        colour.add("red");
        colour.add("white");
    }
}
```

I want to create a list of car object with each item of carNames. But if the car name is 'Audi' or 'BMW' it should create only one object of the class as follow

```
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Specification musicSystem = new Specification("MusicSysten" , "present");
        
        List<Specification> specList= new ArrayList<>();
        specList.add(musicSystem);
        
        carList.add(new Car("Q5", "2020", "Audi", specList));
        carList.add(new Car("X2", "2020", "BMW", specList));
```

But if the item is 'Toyota' then it should create two object each for each color.

```
 List<Specification> specListRed= new ArrayList<>();
        specListRed.add(musicSystem);
        specListRed.add(redColor);

        List<Specification> specListWhite= new ArrayList<>();
        specListWhite.add(musicSystem);
        specListWhite.add(whiteColor);

        carList.add(new Car("Camry", "2020", "Toyota", specListRed));
        carList.add(new Car("Camry", "2020", "Toyota", specListWhite));
```

I am trying to write a common method for creating object and adding to a list. I have tried something like this, but I won't create correct two object for Toyota.

```
carList =  carNames.stream()
                .map(carName -> new Car(model, make, carName, specList))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

please suggest how can I achieve this with streams.

Comment: Not an appropriate use of streams.

Comment: Can look into using `Collection.nCopies` with the caveat of understanding the [difference to a `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543473/collections-ncopies-vs-for-loop-initialization).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the name "Toyota" to be used twice it should be contained in the list of names twice, since the lambda in `map()` is executed for every name.

But inside your map-Call: Where do you get and model & make?

Comment: I will send the make and model as a parameter of the list. I can't add Toyota in the list twice as the color list is not fixed.

Comment: `.forEach` is possibly more appropriate instead of `.map`.

Comment: This does not make real sense @EmrahDiril.. he is aggregating them in a collection

Comment: I think that the combination of lists and specs is not going to work in a general map-call

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand is that `map` operation *always* preserves same amount (i.e. cardinality) as your input.
If you will pass 3 items - no matter which function you have, result will always be 3.

Next thing worth looking into: `flatMap` function. This function can transform any amount of inputs to any amount of results! This looks like what we need.

```
   var carList = carNames.stream()
                .flatMap(carName -> {
                    if (carName.equals("Toyota") {
                      return Stream.of(new Car(model, make, carName, specList1),
                                       new Car(model, make, carName, specList2)); 
                    } else {
                      return Stream.of(new Car(model, make, carName, specList));
                    })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Can we optimize this  ```if (carName.equals("Toyota") {
                      return Stream.of(new Car(model, make, carName, specList1),
                                       new Car(model, make, carName, specList2)); 
                    }``` and I was wondering if I can use streams on the color list

Comment: @codemaster001 - You can write it as `carName -> carName.equals("Toyota") ? Stream.of(new Car(model, make, carName, specList1), new Car(model, make, carName, specList2)) :  Stream.of(new Car(model, make, carName, specList))`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's all about creation and holding of object. Foucus on equals() and and hashcode() methods.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Car)) {
        return false;
    }
    Car car = (Car) o;
    if (carName.equals("BMW")) {
        return true;
    }
    if (carName.equals("Toyota")) {
        return false;
    }
    return Objects.equals(carName , car.carName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 1;
}
```

Driver methood

```
    List<String> carNames = new ArrayList<>();
    carNames.add("Audi");
    carNames.add("BMW");
    carNames.add("Toyota");
    carNames.add("Toyota");
    List<String> colours = new ArrayList<>();
    colours.add("red");
    colours.add("white");

  

     Set carList = carNames.stream()
            .map(carName -> {
                Set ss = new HashSet();
                if (carName.equals("Toyota")) {
                    ss.addAll(colours.stream().map(colr -> new Car("model" , "make" , carName , null)).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                } else {
                    ss.add(new Car("model" , "make" , carName , null));
                }
                return ss;
            })
            .collect(HashSet::new, Set::addAll, Set::addAll);
```